# React Select: How do I force the dropdown to display in order to work on styling?

Tags: react-select

I need to work on the styling of the React Select dropdown options. The way that I normally do CSS styling work is to use use the *Developer Tools* in Chrome, point to an element on the page and start adjusting the CSS properties in the *Styles* tab and see how the elements change.

The trouble with styling React Select's dropdown options is that the options are only visible when the element has focus. And the moment I turn on Developer Tools, the element loses focus and the dropdown disappears!

Is there a way for me to force React Select to show the dropdown options, without the element having focus?

Comment: or you can try react hot loader https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [React Developer Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) so you can force the Select component's `isOpen` state to `true`. Then the dropdown menu will stay open when you fiddle in Chrome's developer tools.

[image: React tab in Chrome's developer tools]

[Source](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/927#issuecomment-256011889)